# Java. Использование jar.

Tags: jar, java

Необходимо использовать функцию, которая находится в некоем jar'e. Исходных кодов нет. Но при этом, не хочется увеличивать свою программу на пару МБ ради одной функции. Можно как то решить такую проблему?

Comment: Пара мегабайт в Java это копейки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам и правда так нужен этот код, то остаётся только один выход: декомпилировать .jar файл, а потом просто скопипастить нужный код к себе.
Во всяком случае, вы просто можете открыть jar через [JD-GUI (~0.5Мб, без установки)](http://jd.benow.ca/), даже не тратя времени на декомпиляцию.

Comment: Совершенного декомпилятора Java не существует: обязательно что-нибудь, да не так преобразуется обратно в Java-код. Так что просто "скопипастить" не получится уж точно..

Comment: По крайней мере, этот декомпилятор себя очень хорошо зарекомендовал, и я не думаю, что он неправильно преобразует всего-лишь один метод...

Comment: Зарекомендовал - это верно. Но суть в том, что если некто попытается декомпилировать таким образом гигантский Java-класс, то таких вот неправильных трансляций будет куева хуча..

Comment: А если класс вовсе и не гигантский? В любом случае, есть ещё и декомпилятор от Mocha...))

Answer (score 2):

Можно декомпилировать!

---

Получите необходимые для ваших действий методы и сами их реализуете у себя в программе

При помощи декомпилятора вы сможете, не только взять какой-то определенный файл из .Jar, но и любой его пакет.

Небольшой список докомпиляторов:

**Java Decompiler**

Видимо, самый популярный декомпилятор Java. Сам он предоставляет консольный интерфейс, уже давно не поддерживается и не обновляется, но все же многие графические инструменты, работающие с данным декомпилятором, до сих пор делают его используемым в случае необходимости декомпиляции небольших Java-классов.

**Mocha**

Является одним из первых выпущенных Java декомпиляторов. Как и JavaDecompiler, Mochaпредоставляет консольный интерфейс, последний релиз состоялся аж в 1996 г.

**DJ Java Decompiler**

Долгое время использовался лишь в качестве графической оболочки Java Decompiler для более быстрой и удобной выборки аргументов командной строки для вызова JAD. Однако в текущей версии наблюдается поддержка аннотаций.

**Fernflower**

Наверно один из лучших декомпиляторов Java-приложений на текущий момент. В последней версии включена поддержка параметрических типов, аннотаций, утверждений, перечисляемых типов, также действительно грамотно декомпилирует байт-код, полученный из-за известных багов компиляторов.

[**Java Decompiler project**](http://jd.benow.ca/)

**JD-Core**

Высоко функциональная библиотека для декомпиляции байт-кода Java, разработка которой велась в рамках «Java Decompiler project». Написана полностью на C++ (необычайно быстра), не требует специальной установки, корректно выполняет свою непосредственную задачу, правда распространяется данный декомпилятор как часть приложения JD-GUI, что не дает возможности ее разработки в стороннем проекте.

В этот проект входят:

- [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/)
- JD-Eclipse
- JD-IntelliJ

Мне лично, очень нравится встроенный декомпилятор в  IDE Intellij Idea, он 
очень качественно разбирает код.
Он настолько крут, что можно зайти в исходники самой java и посмотреть как там и что работает. Ну очень классный продукт...

Единственное о чем хочу сказать: "Помните об авторских правах!". Перед тем как декомпиллировать,  убедитесь, что вы не нарушите закон.
(для себя в тихую можно)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK jar - это zip архив .class файлов. Можете попробовать вытащить только нужный вам .class файл и подключить к своему проекту.

Comment: если только он не тащит за собой еще вереницу классов

Comment: А если "та самая функция" тянет за собой весь джар, то выхода нет

Answer (score 0):

Только одним способом - написать такую же функцию, если конечно это осуществимо.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю воспользоваться аналитическим декомпилятором [Fern flower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fern_flower)
В сове время этот декомпилятор мне очень помог получить код одного коммерческого биллига. Качество работы декомпилятора впонне приемлемое, мне удалось много вытащить с мопощью данного продукта.

Comment: обзор декомпиляторов на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/176825/

Answer (score 0):

А что, если  открыть этот `jar` и посмотреть его `.class` файлы через `IDEA` - это конечно не исходник, но если сильно захотеть, то можно скопипастить нужный метод.

Answer (score -1):

Вот еще один сервис для онлайн декомпиляции jar и class файлов в исходный Java code: [Decompile Android Apk](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)   Быстро и удобно и не надо ничего настраивать.

Answer (score -2):

может вам проще подключить только 1 функцию к исходнику?

```
import lala.blahblah.some_func;
```

Если не использовать декомпиляцию , то это наилучший способ. В код вашей программы добавится только 1 функция, но возникнут зависимости

Comment: 1. При импорте в java ничего никуда не добавляется. Вы просто указываете компилятору, в каких пакетах искать другие классы. Jar-ник тащить все равно придется.
 2. Таким способом можно импортировать только статический метод используя синтаксис: `import static lala.blahblah.SomeClass.someMethod;`